# First set of consecutive integers generated by $am+bn$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, coprime

I am looking for the number of first relatively large set of consecutive positive integers generated by

$$
\{am+bn:\ 0\leq m\leq x,\ 0\leq n\leq y \}
$$
where $a,b$ are given positive integers and $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

For instance; let $a=2$, $b=3$, $x=y=5$, then 
$$
S=\{2,3,4,\ldots,23\}
$$

and let $a=3$, $b=10$, $x=y=20$, then 
$$
S=\{18,19,20,\ldots,242\}
$$
of course the set generated by $am+bn$ with given bounds on $m,n$ is larger but I am looking for the number of the first set of generated successive integers. Is there any know results about this cardinal in terms of $x,y$?

I did some experiment when $x=y$ and I guess this cardinal is about $O(x\log x/\log\log x)$. Am I right? Maybe my question needs to be more clear yet.

Comment: Might be helpful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem

Comment: You don't have $x$ and $y$ in a standard coin problem. With those bounds, my guess is things happen when $x$ and $y$ are small enough for the upper bound and the lower bound to start interacting.